# How to compare two KeyValuePairs using the keys and values' Equals method?

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
var a = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 1);
var b = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 1);

Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));
```

Output:

> True

However, if I try this code:

```
class MyClass : IEquatable<MyClass>
{
    public MyClass(int myProperty)
    {
        MyProperty = myProperty;
    }

    public int MyProperty { get; private set; }

    public bool Equals(MyClass other)
    {
        return other != null &&
               MyProperty == other.MyProperty;
    }
}
.
.
.
var a = new KeyValuePair<int, MyClass>(1, new MyClass(1));
var b = new KeyValuePair<int, MyClass>(1, new MyClass(1));

Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));
```

Then the output is:

> False

My conclusion is that since the keys are value types, they are compared by value, and since the values are reference types, they are compared by reference.

I would like to compare the `KeyValuePair` in a way that the values (as well as the keys) will be compared by value - i.e. using the `Equals` method I provided.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: you can override compare in MyClass and decide how the comparison works

Comment: I suppose, you need to override default method `bool Equals(object o)` and call your IEquatable<MyClass> from it. Take a look at [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the Equals method

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    MyClass other = obj as MyClass;

    return other != null &&
           MyProperty == other.MyProperty;
}
```

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, you will also want to override the [GetHashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) method whenever you override the Equals method. Not doing so will cause a [warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182358.aspx) to be shown on the overridden Equals method, among other issues.

Comment: and `public override int GetHashCode()`

Comment: Yeah, not overriding `GetHashCode()` is pretty much guaranteed to cause issues if you stick your object in any sort of collection.

Comment: @zzxyz Not any type of collection.  Just specifically a hash-based collection.  But yes, you should always be overriding GetHashCode to be in sync with `Equals`, because the consequences of failing to do so when a type *is* used in a hash based collection is pretty bad.

Comment: @Servy bad...and unfortunately...usually a bit subtle. And most collections don't make a point of guaranteeing they don't uses hashes.

Comment: @zzxyz Sure, pretty much nothing guarantees what it *doesn't* use.  You only need to care about any of the things that say they *do* use it.  Anything that doesn't specifically mention that it's using a hash shouldn't expect the objects in it to have a useful hash.  There's pretty much just two collections in .NET that actually use a hash function, Dictionary and HashSet.

Comment: @Servy - That's fair.  I tend to be a little paranoid about what isn't guaranteed, but it's rarely been an issue with C#, and it's hard to say why or that would change for this issue.